# Need to know if I'm writing the correct sentence.

Tags: grammar

I need to know if the sentence is written correctly. This two choices.
1. Let's this year begin.
2. Let's this year begins.

Comment: More detail would allow us to provide a useful answer. Can you tell us what thought you are trying to express?

Answer (score 1):

Well, both are incorrect. Depending on if 'this year' is the subject of the sentence (A), or just an indication of time (B), it should be:

> A) Let this year begin
>
> B) Let's begin this year

Note that "let's" is a contraction of "let us".

But A) doesn't make sense - the year will begin, whether you allow it or not, unlike the famous sentence "Let the games begin".